# How to duplicate rows based on difference in years in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

```
import pandas
data={"Item":"2047125","Model":"HM","Category":"Mechanical","Year":"1984-1988"}
df=pandas.DataFrame(data,index=[0])



      Item   Model    Category       Year
0  2047125    HM     Mechanical    1984-1988
```

I need to duplicate the rows for the difference in years.

```
  Item   Model    Category       Year
2047125    HM     Mechanical     1984
2047125    HM     Mechanical     1985
2047125    HM     Mechanical     1986
2047125    HM     Mechanical     1987
2047125    HM     Mechanical     1988
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

First idea is create lists of all years by custom function and then reshape by [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), working form `0.25+`:

```
def f(x):
    s, e = x.split('-')
    return list(range(int(s), int(e) + 1))

df['Year'] = df['Year'].apply(f)
df = df.explode('Year').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
      Item Model    Category  Year
0  2047125    HM  Mechanical  1984
1  2047125    HM  Mechanical  1985
2  2047125    HM  Mechanical  1986
3  2047125    HM  Mechanical  1987
4  2047125    HM  Mechanical  1988
```

Another solution is use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for helper `DataFrame` `df1`, then use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) by difference of columns with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for new rows and last add values of counter with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df1 = df['Year'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int)
df['Year'] = df1[0].astype(int)
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df1[1] - df1[0] + 1)]
df['Year'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + df['Year']
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
      Item Model    Category  Year
0  2047125    HM  Mechanical  1984
1  2047125    HM  Mechanical  1985
2  2047125    HM  Mechanical  1986
3  2047125    HM  Mechanical  1987
4  2047125    HM  Mechanical  1988
```

Comment: Can you show us performance to compare please(when you have time)

Comment: @jezrael. Thanks. But I get attribute error that df object has no attribute explode.

Comment: @vicky - It working for pandas 0.25+, so use second solution or upgrade pandas

Comment: @anky_91 - Not sure why, but cannot test second solution with timeit.